# Insert line break in postgresql when updating text field

Tags: postgresql, char, sql-update

I am trying to update a text field in a table of my postgresql database.

```
UPDATE public.table SET long_text = 'First Line' + CHAR(10) + 'Second line.' WHERE id = 19;
```

My intended result is that the cell will look like this:

```
First Line
Second line
```

The above syntax returns an error.

Comment: The string concatenation operator in Postgresql is "||", by the way.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You want `chr(10)` instead of `char(10)`.

Be careful with this, because that might be the wrong newline. The "right" newline depends on the client that consumes it. Macs, Windows, and Linux all use different newlines. A browser will expect `<br />`.

It might be safest to write your update using an [escape string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34823171/1175496) for PostgreSQL 9.1+. But read the docs linked below.

```
UPDATE public.table 
SET long_text = E'First Line\nSecond line.' 
WHERE id = 19;
```

The default value of '[standard_conforming_strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-compatible.html)' is 'on' in 9.1+.

```
show standard_conforming_strings;
```

Comment: I used CONCAT('Text 1' , chr(13), 'Text 2') and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

Use a literal newline (if `standard_conforming_strings = on`, i.e. you're on a recent PostgreSQL):

```
UPDATE public.table 
SET long_text = 'First Line
Second line.' 
WHERE id = 19;
```

or you can use an escape:

```
UPDATE public.table 
SET long_text = E'First Line\nSecond line.'
WHERE id = 19;
```

Answer (score 6):

In my version of postgres, \n didnt work for line break and i used \r\n instead, like this:

```
UPDATE public.table 
SET long_text = E'First Liner\r\nSecond line.'
WHERE id = 19;
```

Comment: Is your version of PostgreSQL running on windows?

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL:

varchar + varchar = ERROR.
\ r and \ n is not anywhere that works, for greater compatibility use:

Corret:

```
UPDATE public.table SET 
   long_text = concat('First Line',CHR(13),CHR(10),'Second line.')
WHERE id = 19;
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions are working find but by just entering "Enter" also you can achieve this.

```
UPDATE public.table 
SET long_text = 'First Line
Second line.' 
WHERE id = 19;
```