# What's the "E" before a Postgres string?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, string-literals, wkb

I was reading a Postgres/PostGIS statement like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsBinary(
ST_GeomFromWKB(
  E'\\001\\001\\000\\000\\000\\321\\256B\\312O\\304Q\\300\\347\\030\\220\\275\\336%E@',
  4326
  )
);
```

The above creates something from a Well Known Binary (WKB). I haven't seen the specific way of quoting here where the string is single quoted with a `E` preceding the beginning quote.

What is this format called? And what are the formatting rules for this? e.g. is the `336%E@` at the very end special or just some binary value?

This is with Postgres9.3/9.4; PostGIS 2.1.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As per the PostgreSQL documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-syntax-lexical.html (emphasis mine)

> PostgreSQL also accepts "escape" string constants, which are an extension to the SQL standard. **An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter `E` (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote**, e.g., `E'foo'`. (When continuing an escape string constant across lines, write `E` only before the first opening quote.) Within an escape string, a backslash character (`\`) begins a C-like backslash escape sequence, in which the combination of backslash and following character(s) represent a special byte value

The use of `\\` in your string means that it's escaping an escape sequence, probably to be safe in transit and storage in a `.sql` file. The *verbatim* string actually passed into the `ST_GeomFromWKB` function will be:

```
\001\001\000\000\000\321\256B\312O\304Q\300\347\030\220\275\336%E@
```

These sequences of 3 or 4 characters between slashes would then be interpreted by `ST_GeoFromWKB` directly.

The documentation for `ST_GeoFromWKB` ( https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromWKB.html ) states:

> The `ST_GeomFromWKB` function, takes a well-known binary representation of a geometry and a Spatial Reference System ID (`SRID`) and creates an instance of the appropriate geometry type. This function plays the role of the Geometry Factory in SQL. This is an alternate name for `ST_WKBToSQL`.

Unfortunately it doesn't state what format, exactly, the "well-known binary representation" actually is.

It turns out that the content of the string depends on the coordinate system you're using, which is specified by the `SRID` parameter. In this case `4326` corresponds to `WGS84`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84

You'll need to do further reading and research to untangle that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the `4326` SRID part. But not `304Q`, and `336%E@`. They do not seem like hexidecimals as the wikipedia says: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary . I've just asked another question at GIS.SE: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177075/how-to-interpret-a-wkb-well-known-binary about this.

Answer (score 9):

What you *see* does not look like hexadecimal, because the [`bytea`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860) **string literal** is in [escape string syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729) (which is rather outdated nowadays).

```
E'\\001\\001\\000\\000\\000\\321\\256B\\312O\\304Q\\300\\347\\030\\220\\275\\336%E@'
```

The same as "standard conforming string":

```
'\001\001\000\000\000\321\256B\312O\304Q\300\347\030\220\275\336%E@'
```

Both are in ["escape format"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html#AEN5675), which can be represented more efficiently in ["hex format"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html#AEN5666) as:

```
'\x0101000000d1ae42ca4fc451c0e71890bdde254540'
```

You can use [`encode()` and `decode()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115271/what-is-the-optimal-data-type-for-an-md5-field/115316#115316) to transform one form into the other.

I answered your [follow-up question on gis.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/177076/7244) with more details.

Answer (score 0):

ex:

(in & after version 9.1)

```sql
select '\n'; -- \n -- literal string <=> r'\n' in py
select E'\n'; -- (a newline) -- escapable string
select '\u0024'; -- \u0024
select E'\u0024'; -- $ (a dollar sign)
select '\\u0024'; -- \\u0024
select E'\\u0024'; -- \u0024
```

--

***warning for: `standard_conforming_strings` in diff version***

> If the configuration parameter [standard_conforming_strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) is `off`, then PostgreSQL recognizes backslash escapes in both regular and escape string constants. However, as of PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is `on`, meaning that backslash escapes are recognized only in escape string constants.
>
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE