# How to do <Enter> in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to pair together two texts from two tables with the Enter character between them.

What I did so far is:

```
select text1 || '
' || text2
from A
join B u
using (id)
```

For example if: `text1='Hello'` and `text2='World'`

it will give:

```
Hello
World
```

the

```
|| '
    ' ||
```

gives the `Enter` key.  Is there another way to do it something like ascii code or what ever? It feels stiuped to do it this way.

Note: This is PoostgreSql question. I initially tagged it this way. Answers from SQL SERVER does not apply here.

Comment: `text1 '||chr(10)||' text2'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name shouldn't `chr(13)` work too?

Comment: Flagging duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string

Comment: @serv: depends on your platform.

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra This is Postgresql question. Not SQL SERVER

Comment: Solution found: chr(10)  from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638615/insert-line-break-in-postgresql-when-updating-text-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `\n`:

```
select text1 || E'\n' || text2
from A
join B u
using (id)
```

Comment: It will print Hello\nWorld

Comment: Forgot the capital E for marking the escape string constant

Comment: What is the diffrance between that and chr(10)?

Comment: There is none, really. Both insert a line feed. chr(10) takes the 11 ASCII character (index 10), which is a Line feed.